# Unknow discs and windows space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk, user-space

I've been using ubuntu for a while and today decided to uninstall windows from my notebook so I could use the space it occupied on ubuntu. However, after the removal I found some disks hanging in my launcher bar and don't know what are they or I'm supposed to do with it, and the capacity of ubuntu HD remains the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Have a nice day

Before the uninstalling

http://postimg.org/image/6vkauigrx/

http://postimg.org/image/vribvqstp/

(the rest of the pics are in the comments).

Comment: After the uninstalling

http://postimg.org/image/zd66rkwi9/

http://postimg.org/image/w53criftz/

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. Make a system backup (Read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) how to do this. You're user type 4)
2. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD,
3. Go to the dash,
4. Type 'gparted`,
5. **Delete** the partitions that contain nothing (without light yellow, or marked "NTFS")
6. You can now click the Ubuntu partitions and drag them into the empty area
7. Click "Apply"
8. Reboot

### Done!

Comment: Thanks! Could I just run gparted directly from ubuntu instead from the CD? I putted the CD, hitted dash, then came a screen where there was no room to type. Whyn I finally got to type, it appeard "boot error".I tried restarting the system and hitting "c" for the command line, but grub showed "error recognizing command 'gparted'". Anyway, even if I could run it, I'd still be stuck at this point: http://postimg.org/image/mlxh7vqm7/. You said I should delete all non-yellow partitions, that includes ext3? It has like 5OOgb in it rsrs.

Comment: you NEED to do this from a boot CD!  Otherwise what you're doing is like a doctor operating on himself at home!  :P  ;-) Download the [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/download.php): it's small and only contains Gparted! (start downloading that now while I type the rest)

Comment: First boot normally in Ubuntu, then open the drives that showed up and copy all files to your home directory. then reboot in the gparted CD, delete the ext3 and then click and drag the ext4 to the left until it is next to the NTFS.  then click apply operations and then go to sleep (ensure you are hooked up to power! this will take several hours!)

Comment: And if it all works, you should click the little grey icon under the 0 which means "yes this answer is valid"

Comment: @Ricardo: an accept by clicking the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green [would be nice](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)...